# iPhone 3GS on T-Mobile Connecting to iTunes Question

Tags: itunes, jailbreak, iphone

I just purchased iPhone 3GS. Currently it is running Version OS 4.0.1. Now if I update my iTunes on my Mac and plug then connect the iPhone to the Mac to sync it then will it brick or not.

I need the latest version of iTunes on my Mac for iPhone development but I don't want to push the latest version of OS to my iPhone or else there is a danger of bricking the device!

Can someone please enlighten me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading iTunes will not force you to upgrade iOS on your 3GS.

Upgrade your iTunes with 3GS disconnected. And when you connect your 3GS to iTunes it will say that an update is available and ask you "Download?" or "Download and Install?" From here, you can choose to just download the new iOS upgrade and not install.

This downloaded file will come in handy when you want to upgrade to jailboken version of that new iOS.